# converting a string to a list from a text file

Tags: python

```
with open('task3randomtext.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
```

this is the code I use to take text from a text file and read it into my program but it reads it in as a list an will not let me split it to convert it to a array. Is there any other way or splitting it or reading it in.

Comment: What _other_ way? What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried text.split() and an error came up saying 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: readlines creates a list of strings -- one each for the lines in your file.  You can loop on text with a for loop and split each list item into what you want

Comment: What do you mean "it reads it in as a string"? `readlines` returns a list, not a string.

Comment: Just, *please*, take a look at the docs for Python, or read a beginners tutorial, or, even better, the documetation about `file.readlines()`!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Python documentation ([which you should](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)!) you can see that readlines() returns a list containing every line in the file. To then split each line, you could do something along the lines of:

```
with open('times.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line.split()
```